# How to fit single polynomial curve to scatter plot

Tags: python, scatter-plot, data-fitting

```
[from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from astropy.io import ascii
from scipy.stats import norm
import math
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

data2  = pd.read_csv("Dispersion total.csv")
names = data2.columns
df = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=names)
df.head()


data3 = pd.read_csv("Dispersion less than equal to -1.5.csv")
names1 = data3.columns
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns=names1)
df1.head()

x= df1['Mean Mag'].values
y=df1['Log(sigma)'].values

#print(y)

w= df['Mean Mag'].values
z=df['Log(sigma)'].values


#ax=data2.plot(kind= 'scatter',x= 'Mean Mag',y = 'Log(sigma)',color='green')
#data3.plot(kind= 'scatter',x= 'Mean Mag',y = 'Log(sigma)',ax=ax)

fit = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
a = fit[0]
b = fit[1]
c = fit[2]
fit_equation = a * np.square(x) + b * x + c
#Plotting
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, fit_equation,color = 'r',alpha = 0.5, label = 'Polynomial fit')
ax1.scatter(w,z, s = 4, color = 'b', label = 'Data points')
ax1.set_title('Polynomial fit example')
ax1.legend()

plt.xlabel('Mean Magnitude')
plt.ylabel('Log(sigma)')
plt.show()
```

This is the plot I currently have : [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pws4M.png)

I want a polynomial fit to my data that doesn't try to fit every point but a general curve in the most dense region (between -1.75 to -1.5).Something like this:

[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5m2W.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could define the fit equation as a Python function. Then you can use that function to calculate the model y values for a dense array of x values and pass those to the plotting method:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

X_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Y_data = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5]

a, b, c = np.polyfit(X_data, Y_data, 2)
fit_equation = lambda x: a * x ** 2 + b * x + c

def plot_fit(X, Y, f):
    X_fit = np.linspace(min(X), max(X), 1000)
    Y_fit = f(X_fit)

    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.plot(X_fit, Y_fit, color='r', alpha=0.5, label='Polynomial fit')
    ax1.scatter(X, Y, s=4, color='b', label='Data points')
    ax1.set_title('Polynomial fit example')
    ax1.legend()
    plt.show()
    
plot_fit(X_data, Y_data, fit_equation)
```

[image: polynomial fit]

Increasing the polynomial degree will result in a closer fit:

```py
a, b, c, d, e = np.polyfit(X_data, Y_data, 4)
fit_equation = lambda x: a * x**4 + b * x**3 + c * x**2 + d * x + e
    
plot_fit(X_data, Y_data, fit_equation)
```

[image: polynomial fit with higher degree]

So you can choose the degree such that you keep the curve within the dense region. Removing outliers before calculating the fit would be another option.

Comment: See also the new [numpy API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit)